# Receive image after re sizing from source

Tags: php, sql-server, image, resize

How to receive an image file with reduced size from server by direct linking?
Explained: Actual url= http://domain.com/image.jpg has h=200, with=200
I want this file with already reduced from server to 50 by 50.
Now get file url= http://anotherDomain.com?file=http://domain.com/image.jpg&h=50&w=50

Comment: Lookup http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php in order to get that type of url working.  Also note, that unless you are using `.htaccess` to modify the url, it will need to be `image.php?...`

Comment: And.. why not?  Because you don't understand or...?

Comment: I want direct link to do that.

Comment: @Jon Do you have any code for that?